# Javascript/Jquery Post and Get?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

Is it possible to have a piece of code or a function that does the following.

I would like for a javascript file to send a request to a different domain  of mine with a variable. This webpage would check the variable against the database and return to the original javascript file the result of being either TRUE or FALSE

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Have a google for `jsonp`.

Comment: [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are sending requests between domains, you should have a look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ with the `dataType` set to `jsonp` to load the response using a script tag.

More details on JSONP: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jsonp

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know of JSONP and used a diffrent approach

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    crossDomain:true,
    url: 'http://otherdomain/check.php',
    success: function(data) { 
        // check.php response
    }
});
```

and in check.php

```
<?php
$allowable_hosts = array('http://originaldomain','http://anotherdomain');
if (in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'],$allowable_hosts))
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
//echo "ok"; - your check code
?>
```